# Does there need to be a comma after football?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> 1. We can play football or watch a movie.
> 2. We can watch football, or watch a movie.

Does there need to be a comma after football?

Comment: No there doesn't

Answer (score 1):

#### No comma is needed here.

Commas separate clauses, items in lists, parenthetical phrases, etc. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma) describes it well enough.

You only have two items in your “list”, so none of these cases apply here. No comma is needed.

> ✔️**Yes:** We can watch football or watch a movie.

#### If you have three items...

You need the comma, and you might want an [Oxford comma.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)

> ✔️**Yes:** We can watch football, take a hike or watch a movie.
>
> ✔️ **Yes:** We can watch football, take a hike, or watch a movie.

Answer (score 0):

With *only 2 items* the rule is clear: *without the comma.*

With 3 or more items the situation about the comma *before the final “or” (or “and”)* is more complicated:

- *British English* allows constructions *with or without* the comma.
- In *American English* the comma is *almost mandatory.*
- In *Canadian English* the comma is *almost forbidden.*
- *Australian English* allows constructions *with or without* the comma, but *without* it is a more typical one.

(The word *"almost"* means here that there are still debates about this subject.)

Comment: A comma isn't needed, but it isn't prohibited, either.